# How to convert milliseconds(integer) to string in mm:ss format?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I format data of the type integer stored in milliseconds to minutes and seconds in sqlite? How can I modify the query below to be displayed in minutes:seconds format?

```
select milliseconds
from table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  substr(datetime(mycol/1000,'unixepoch'),-5)
from    mytable
;
```